# What is Alias Domain?

Tags: web-hosting, domains

I notice that many hosting providers provide a feature named "Alias Domain".
What it is? and how can it benefit me?

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this is related to using web apps. Seems like more of a webmasters question.

Answer (score 1):

Domain  Aliases are domains that are associated with your primary domain.  Examples of usage are:

- You have registered `ahmed.com` you may want to set up a Domain Alias for `ahmed.co.uk` so that any requests for the `.co.uk` site are automatically transferred to `.com`
- They are also useful to redirect users in the event of them misspelling.  So you could create a Domain Alias for `ahemed.com` to redirect user to `ahmed.com`
- The last common usage is for email domains.  If you have two email domains, `ahemed.com` and `myotheremail.com` you could alias `myotheremail.com` so that all email will be delivered to `ahmed.com`

A live example would be if you entered `www.microsft.com` in to your browser - this will redirect you to `http://www.microsoft.com/en/us/default.aspx`

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't think thats a good example... when you entered microsoft.com you actually went to microsoft.com. That's not a good example of Domain Alias. The one of ahmed.com and ahmed.co.uk is in fact a good example

Comment: @sebastian - My example is if you enter `microsft.com` you are redirected to `microsoft.com` Note the first one is missing an 'O'  This is an example of Domain Alias to cater for misspellings.

Answer (score 0):

It's just another way to get to the same physical folder. Say you have domain1.com and domain2.com, and your web hosts stores these in `/home/yourname/domain1.com`, creating domain2.com as an alias would serve what's in `/home/yourname/domain1.com` when someone types domain2.com in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Domain mirroring is a feature that pretty much all web hosts have. It's just not a very useful feature and really isn't even worth mentioning. You'd rarely need or want 2 domains to mirror each other. It's far better for SEO purposes and for usability to just redirect one domain to another to prevent having duplicate content.

I wouldn't base your hosting decision on this feature. Focus on more useful features like SSH/shell access, SFTP, server-side scripting languages (e.g. PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.), crontab access, RDBMS (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.), cpanel access, and large storage/bandwidth quotas. Also make sure there aren't any arbitrary limits or fees on mundane features like email accounts/ftp accounts/subdomains/etc